# In C#, on startup, is there a way to force the JIT compiler to touch all MSIL code in the entire app?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

We have a C# program that performs some timing measurements. Unfortunately, the first time it measures is 20x slower than the second and subsequent times, probably due to JIT (Just-In-Time) compiling.

Is there a way to ensure, on startup, that every line of MSIL code in the entire application is compiled with the JIT compiler?

Comment: Well, it is of course *accurate* timing.  Not always a good idea to ignore what's really going on.  Ngen is no panacea, slow startups can be caused by *cold starts*, the effort of finding the DLLs on the disk.  Ngen actually makes them worse, more DLLs to find.  Jitting can be faster than finding a DLL if the assembly is smallish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ta.speot.is said, the answer is probably using NGEN; this is a tool the pre-jits your assembly and turns it into native code for the platform you're running on.

Often its run during the setup phase of your application because of this.

MSDN have a guide here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Ended up writing a function that calls ngen.exe on the entry executable. This automatically JITs all sub-assemblies. The technique works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use NGEN, as suggested by [@ta.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9583460/267) in the comment, or by [@Russ C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15697/russ-c) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583506/267), a different way is to "warm up" the JITter for the code involved.

Basically, if you call some code 1000s of times in order to do performance measurements, you call it once without timing it, just to JIT all the code, before you do the actual measurements.

ie. something like this:

```
MethodUnderTest();

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
    MethodUnderTest();
sw.Stop();
```